# OSGi service not implementing interface

Tags: java, osgi

I am working on a project which uses OSGi which has below code

```
@Component(policy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, ds = true, immediate = true, metatype = false)
@Service(TestInterface.class)
public class TestInterface{
```

Here the code doesn't implement the interface in which the service is going to exposed. Also I have verified everywhere this is not referenced anywhere with @Reference.
Does it really need to make it as service instead of only component? In case if i want to use it in another Component i have to make it as a service by implementing interface. 
Does OSGI really mandates the service to be exposed should implements interface?

Comment: There is no @Service in declarative services. What type of annotations do you use?

Comment: felix scr annotations

Comment: Where is that @Service annotation coming from?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, Here is the link for [Felix SCR annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#service). I landed this thread thinking about same question, in one my project there is similar service without interface and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

An OSGi service can be registered under any type name not just interfaces. Interfaces are highly recommended since they nicely separate the implementation class from consumers of the service.